# matlab randomly sample variable x times to get mean of y

Tags: matlab, select, mean, random

I have a variable `age` which contains the age of 100 patients (ages 20 to 80).

I would like to write code to randomly select 10 patients from this sample of 100 patients (one patient can appear more than once) to get a mean age of 45.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Comment: [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) if you have the stats toolbox. Or just generate [random integers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/random-integers.html) to index with.

Comment: We are not here to write your code. Please try something first and if you get stuck in a try, ask a question which includes a [mcve] detailing the code you have trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

I was originally looking to understand if there is a function in Matlab that can be used to solve this problem.  However, none of the commands relating to rand appear to do what I need it to do (my apologies if I missed it).

However, I have written the following code that seems to fix my problem.  In the loop I allow for 0.1 variation from the desired mean (which can be adapted as needed).

```
% Make an array of 100 ages between 20 and 80
min=20;
max=80;
AgeArray = min + (max-min).*rand(100,1);

% Set parameters for randomselection
samplenr=10;              % Want a 10 random samples from the original age array of 100
mean = 45;                % The mean of randomly selected 10 sample should be 45
half_nr=samplenr/2;       % Set the half-way point

% Get first random sample of 10 ages from the original array of 100 
RandSubSample = datasample(AgeArray,samplenr);

% Sort the array of 10 from low to high values
RandSubSample=sort(RandSubSample);

% Mean of this random sample
sumage=sum(RandSubSample);
meanage=sumage/samplenr;



% Loop to re-select 10 samples until mean matches 45 (with error allowed for +/-
% 0.1
while meanage<mean-0.1 || meanage>mean+0.1

if meanage<mean                 % If mean is too low we need to replace young ages with older aged

    index=randi([1 half_nr]);
    RandSubSample(index)=r(randi(numel(r)));

elseif meanage>mean             % If mean is too high we need to replace old age with younger age

    index=randi([half_nr nr]);
    RandSubSample(index)=r(randi(numel(r)));

end

RandSubSample=sort(RandSubSample);

sumage=sum(RandSubSample);
meanage=sumage/nr;

end
y=sort(y);

sumage=sum(y);
meanage=sumage/nr;

end
```